Facing issue for Azure Function with Dot Net 8 at locally in Visual Studio Code
I have created a C# function in Azure using Visual Studio Code and followed the below steps to

Select a language for your function project  --> Choose C#.
Select a .NET runtime -- > Choose .NET 8.0 Isolated (LTS).
Select a template for your project's first function  --> Choose HTTP trigger.1
Provide a function name Type --> HttpExample.
Provide a namespace Type --> My.Functions.
Authorization level  --> Choose Anonymous.
open your project -->Select Open in current window.

after this steps i build and tried to run the app locally,
I got error:
dotnet run
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.GetFunctionsHostGrpcUri(IConfiguration configuration) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 97


how to resolve this issue?
I have tried same steps for .NET 6.0 Isolated (LTS). version its working and running perfectly fine.
I have also updated and install relevant required tools and package updates for .net version 8 but still facing the error.

You might find something that applies also to you case here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2121

I see you are trying to run an Azure isolated function using dotnet run command but you need to use func host start or func start command to run an Azure function.
I have created a default .Net8 isolated function using the template in visual studio code and my function code looks like below-
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpTrigger1> _logger;

        public HttpTrigger1(ILogger<HttpTrigger1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("HttpTrigger1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}

In order to run the function either navigate to Run -> Start Debugging or Run without Debugging in visual studio code. You can also execute your function using func host start or func start command in terminal as shown below-
C:\Users\********\Documents\functionApp\78437173> func host start
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  78437173 -> C:\Users\*******\Documents\functionApp\78437173\bin\output\78437173.dll
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Temp\oclw0pui.c1o\WorkerExtensions.csproj (in 456 ms).
  WorkerExtensions -> C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\oclw0pui.c1o\buildout\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.00



Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5530 Commit hash: N/A +c8883e7f3c06e2b424fbac033806c19d8d91418c (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.28.5.21962

[2024-05-06T15:19:21.268Z] Found C:\Users\********\Documents\functionApp\78437173\78437173.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-06T15:19:23.031Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-06T15:19:27.972Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-05-06T15:19:36.617Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=8a2b699d-77c1-4d02-8cbf-065df810e03f)
[2024-05-06T15:19:36.960Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-05-06T15:19:36.976Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-05-06T15:19:37.097Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=8a2b699d-77c1-4d02-8cbf-065df810e03f, Duration=476ms)


I have also tried to execute function with func host start or func start, but its creating issue for

I have also tried to execute function with "func host start or func start", but its creating issue -- PS C:\abcd\AzureFunctionApp> func start
MSBuild ver17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.------------------   Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:    4.0.5148 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Ver: 4.17.3.20392 [2024-05-07T07:32:37.728Z] No job functions found. Try your job classes /methods public. [2024-05-07T07:32:42.674Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000593BA36F'.

please share your local settings file and .csproj file

@ShreeShivayNamastubhyam do you have "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" in local settings file?

I can see only below code which is by default created at the time of function created as --{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
}
}

@ShreeShivayNamastubhyam set "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" and try

i tried with set   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"  but same issue still persist

can you please share your .csproj file and function.cs file

my .csproj file is looks like  --> 

net8.0
v4
Exe
enable
enable



  continue in next comment as --









PreserveNewest


PreserveNewest
Never






@ShreeShivayNamastubhyam have you tried to execute your function by navigating to Run-> start debugging ? Also please update your Azure Functions Core Tools to the latest version.

Yes I have tried to execute my function by navigating to Run-> start debugging  still issue is persist  and azure function tool version v1.14.3

@ShreeShivayNamastubhyam Update the Azure function tool version to the latest one as you are using old version. If you have visual studio then try to create the function from there, I believe it will work

As i checked latest version details for the azure function its showing on official site is the same as Version - 1.14.34  and  Last Updated on -04/30/2024

@ShreeShivayNamastubhyam from your output I see you are using Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version: 4.0.5148 Commit hash: N/A (64-bit) Function Runtime Ver: 4.17.3.20392 but latest one is Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit) Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

Hey Ikhtesam Afrin, Thankls buddy for your great quick support and suggestions for the above recent comment, i.e., Update Azure Functions Core tools to 4.0.5700 my older version has issue when i update it its works for me

Here below some steps tried to resolve the given issue..
initially I have followed the steps for setup using (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=node-v4%2Cpython-v2%2Cisolated-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp )
Then also did some updates for make it run as below :

I have update the Azure Functions Package version -v1.14.3
Also update the Azure Function Core tool latest version - v4 (Core Tools Version:
4.0.5700) and (Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572)
Used terminal command to execute function locally in vs code as "func host start"



Special Thanks to  Ikhtesam Afrin for helping me here to get it done. Appreciated  your support  for the great helping suggestions :)
